# How can I correctly add a cookie using selenium-webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write bare bones unit tests using [`selenium-webdriver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver). In order to correctly test my application, I need to prepare each test case with a cookie.

I am trying to do the following:

```
it('should set cookies', async function() {
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    driver.manage().window().setSize(800, 600);
    await driver.manage().addCookie({
        name: 'KEY',
        value: 'COOKIE-VALUE',
        domain: '.my.domain',
        path: '/',
        secure: false
    });
    await driver.get('http://test.my.domain');
    // test following....
});
```

My tests run (i.e. calling `addCookie` does not throw/reject), but the set cookie values will not be used when the browser makes a request against my application.

When I try to log the set cookies like:

```
await driver.manage().addCookie({
    name: 'KEY',
    value: 'COOKIE-VALUE',
    domain: '.my.domain',
    path: '/',
    secure: false
});

const set = await driver.manage().getCookies();
console.log('set', set);
```

it will tell me that no cookies have been set:

```
set []
```

I also dug into the sources of `selenium-webdriver` and able to use the debugger to find out that the correct cookie string will be constructed and [enqueued here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/4cf028acb2331b747f2eb6395fc344effe8226c9/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1248-L1259).

How do I correctly add a cookie so that it will be used by the driver instance?

---

For those wondering about `async/await`, I have disabled the managed promises using:

```
webdriver.promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `addCookie` add a cookie to the current domain, so you'll first have to navigate to the targeted URL to set the domain:

```
await driver.get('http://test.my.domain');
await driver.manage().addCookie({
    name: 'KEY',
    value: 'COOKIE-VALUE',
    domain: 'test.my.domain',
    path: '/',
    secure: false
});
```

https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#add-cookie

Comment: Does this mean if my server needs the browser to send the cookie I need to use `get` => `addCookie` => `get` or is there a shortcut to this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any shortcut. You only need to call `get` if the current domain is not the expected one for the cookie. The cookie will then remain and be sent to the server as long as the browser remains open.